# Are the starting stats of a character important?

Tags: shot-online

In Shot Online, there are a number of different characters that can be chosen when starting out. They come with slightly different stats, which *can* be reset (but this requires a special item and is usually not done until much later in the game).

Now, reading from the game forum, having points in *stamina* is generally considered a waste. Does this effectively mean that Wotan (the character with the most base stamina) is the worst starting character?

Or are the starting stats only a marginal difference (in which case going for a character whose looks you like would be more important)?